# actionlistener not working and sound is not playing but no errors

Tags: java, actionlistener

the sound i used doesn't play and it doesn't use the actionlistener.. i have the              soundclip in wav and it is in the directory of the class.. please help me..i dont get what is the problem with my coding

```
public class Willy extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Button play,stop;
    Container pane=getContentPane();
    AudioClip audioClip;
    Date date = new Date();//new command 4
    Timer timer = new Timer (1000,this);
    int eye1=50,eye2=45,pupil=10;
    int r=255,g=255,b=255;
    Color white=new Color(255,255,255);
    Color black=new Color(0,0,0);
    JLabel label;


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
    setSize(1000,1000);
    setLayout(null);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;//new command 2
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));

            g.drawOval(83,6,321,303);//outer head
            g.setColor(new Color(255,102,0));//orange
            g.fillOval(83,6,321,303);//outer head color
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);//black
            g.drawLine(151,282,93,391);//left arm outer
            g.drawArc(93,350,60,80,180,125);//left hand arc
            g.drawLine(93,390,140,425);//left hand line
            g.drawLine(140,425,155,395);//left arm inside
            g.drawLine(335,282,365,391);//right arm outer
    g.drawOval(335,387,40,40);//right hand
    g.drawArc(335,390,20,20,35,-105);//right finger
    g.drawLine(336,415,325,385);//right arm inside
    g.drawLine(150,405,150,435);//left torso
    g.drawLine(330,400,330,435);//right torso
    g.drawLine(150,435,330,435);//bottom torso
    g.drawLine(240,435,240,410);//zipper
    g.drawLine(160,450,320,450);//bottom leg
    g.drawLine(160,435,160,450);//left leg
    g.drawLine(320,435,320,450);//right leg
    g.drawLine(160,450,150,465);//left foot
    g.drawLine(320,450,330,465);//right foot
    g.drawLine(150,465,330,465);//bottom foot
    g.drawOval(125,40,235,235);//inner head
    g.setColor(new Color(139,69,19));//brown
    g.fillOval(155,65,180,180);//smallest head color
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(155,65,180,180);//smallest head
    g.setColor(new Color(255,228,196));//hoodie hole color
    g.fillOval(195,65,100,180);//hoodie hole color
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(195,65,100,180);//hoodie hole
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(195,115,eye1,eye2);//left eye
    g.drawOval(245,115,eye1,eye2);//right eye
    g.setColor(white);
    g.fillOval(195,115,eye1,eye2);
    g.fillOval(245,115,eye1,eye2);
    g.setColor(black);
    g.fillOval(215,135,10,10);//left pupil color
    g.fillOval(265,135,10,10);//right pupil color
    g.drawOval(215,135,pupil,pupil);//left pupil
    g.drawOval(265,135,pupil,pupil);//right pupil

    Polygon x=new Polygon();//torso color  new command 1
    x.addPoint(151,182);
    x.addPoint(93,391);
    x.addPoint(140,425);
    x.addPoint(155,395);
    x.addPoint(150,405);
    x.addPoint(150,435);
    x.addPoint(330,435);
    x.addPoint(330,400);
    x.addPoint(325,385);
    x.addPoint(336,415);

    Polygon leg=new Polygon();
    leg.addPoint(150,435);
    leg.addPoint(330,435);
    leg.addPoint(330,450);
    leg.addPoint(160,450);
    leg.addPoint(160,435);

    Polygon q=new Polygon();
    q.addPoint(342,308);
    q.addPoint(335,282);
    q.addPoint(332,285);
    q.addPoint(329,288);
    q.addPoint(326,289);
    q.addPoint(323,291);
    q.addPoint(320,293);
    q.addPoint(318,294);
    q.addPoint(315,296);
    q.addPoint(313,297);
    q.addPoint(312,299);
    q.addPoint(310,299);
    q.addPoint(307,300);
    q.addPoint(303,301);
    q.addPoint(300,303);
    q.addPoint(294,305);
    q.addPoint(279,307);

    Polygon h=new Polygon();
    h.addPoint(336,415);
    h.addPoint(325,385);
    h.addPoint(325,415);

    Polygon t=new Polygon();
    t.addPoint(336,415);
    t.addPoint(310,365);
    t.addPoint(345,360);
    t.addPoint(342,315);
    t.addPoint(365,391);
    t.addPoint(361,388);
    t.addPoint(358,385);

    Polygon foot=new Polygon();
    foot.addPoint(320,450);
    foot.addPoint(330,465);
    foot.addPoint(150,465);
    foot.addPoint(160,450);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    g.setColor(new Color(255,102,0));
    g.fillPolygon(x);
    g.fillPolygon(t);
    g.fillRect(200,308,125,100);
    g.fillRect(220,308,122,70);
    g.fillPolygon(h);
    g.fillPolygon(q);
    g.fillPolygon(leg);
    g.setColor(new Color(139,69,19));
    g.fillOval(335,387,40,40);
    g.fillArc(93,350,60,80,180,125);
    g.fillPolygon(foot);

    // TUNOG

    play = new Button("  Play   ");

    //Set Location and Size
    play.setLocation(800, 200);
    play.setSize(50,50);
    //Add sa Applet para makita
    add(play);

    //Add Listener sa button para mag karoon sya ng saysay
    play.addActionListener(this);

    stop = new Button("  Stop  ");
    stop.setLocation(800, 250);
    stop.setSize(50,50);
    add(stop);
    stop.addActionListener(this);
    //audioClip = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(),"kenny_1.au");

}



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
     Button source = (Button)e.getSource();
      if (source.getLabel().equals("  Play   ")){
         audioClip.play();
         eye2=5;
         pupil=5;
         white=new Color(0,0,0);
         black=new Color(255,228,196);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,date.toString());
         repaint();
      }
      else if(source.getLabel() .equals("  Stop  ")){
      audioClip.stop();
      eye2=50;
      pupil=10;
      white=new Color(255,255,255);
      black=new Color(0,0,0);
      repaint();//new command 3
      }

}
```

}

Comment: Do not use labels of buttons for comparison. Instead use button objects themselves. Also the part of code that gets the audio clip has been commented. That is also a reason that the code may not be working.

Comment: i used that earlier and it worked but when i closed my eclipse and opend it again it didn't work anymore

Comment: What about the commented getAudioClip() function?

Comment: it didn't have comment earlier and it still didn't play

Comment: thank you sir.. the actionlistener now works.. but still no sounds

Comment: Check if the file is actually being accessed by the program. Also check if the file is in the proper place.

Comment: it is in the same folder as the class and java file and it is in wav format

Comment: i changed it. it has kenny_1.au here i tried changing the file to kenny.wav

Comment: sadly no and it has no errors thats why its driving me crazy

Comment: Add System.out.println(""); statements to see if the file is properly accessed, if the play button works correctly, and also check if getAudioClip is working properly as you want it to. That is all I can say.

Comment: the sound file is working. how can i check if its being accessed by the applet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getCodeBase() checks in the Bin folder of your project. So make sure your file that you want to play is present in the Bin folder.

I tested it with the following code:

```
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class audioPlayer extends JApplet{

    AudioClip aClip;

    public void init(){
        System.out.print("Getting audio clip!");
        aClip = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "tetris.wav");
        System.out.print("Looping audio clip!");
        aClip.loop();
    }

}
```

The code above works perfectly fine and plays the sound perfectly.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR!! i didn't know it has to be in the bin folder

Comment: You are welcome. And please don't call me, sir. (I am only 19 and most probably younger than you :D)